# Is there a way of logging the browser a user submits a form from in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, browser

I have a PHP page which handles the submission of a form and adds the data to a MySQL table.  I am wondering if there is a way of writing the browser and version that a user is submitting the form from into a column in the MySQL table?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information is available in:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

The function [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/function.get-browser.php) is capable of parsing it out to some degree:

```
$browserinfo = get_browser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
print_r($browserinfo);

echo $browserinfo['browser']; // firefox
echo $browserinfo['platform']; // linux
```

Note: It's not actually necessary to pass the user agent variable into `get_browser()` as I've done above - it reads that header by default.